# How do I calculate an exponentially weighted moving mean using DSP signal processing toolbox

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, mean

I am using MATLAB R2020a with MacOS. I am trying to find the exponentially weighted moving mean of the cycle period of an ECG signal, and have used the dsp.MovingAverage function from the DSP signal processing toolbox, and called the commands shown. However, I am not sure how to specify how many of the elements of the vector to include in the weighted mean. At the moment, is it just adding a weight to all of the elements and then finding the moving mean?

movavgExp = dsp.MovingAverage('Method', 'Exponential weighting', 'ForgettingFactor', 0.1);

Whenever I call the 'WindowLength' command as specified in the DSP documentation, it produces an error:

```
    movavgExp = dsp.MovingAverage(10, 'Method', 'Exponential weighting', 'ForgettingFactor', 0.1);

    Warning: The WindowLength property is not relevant in this configuration of the System
```

object.

I would really appreciate any suggestions for this, thanks in advance!

Comment: From the Mathworks page for `dsp.MovingAverage`: "Exponential weighting — The block multiplies the samples by a set of weighting factors. The magnitude of the weighting factors decreases exponentially as the age of the data increases, but the magnitude never reaches zero. To compute the average, the algorithm sums the weighted data.". So there is no real averaging window as you use all your signal up to time `t` (exponentially weighted) for the mean value at that instant.

Comment: Of course older samples are weighted less than newer ones, and the parameter for that is that `ForgettingFactor`. I guess you could then define an "effective" averaging window as the number of samples whose weight is larger than a threshold ...

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this suggestion. I was wondering how I would access the 'weights' variable in order to exclude values from the mean whose weights were below that for any point in time?

Answer (score 0):

From the Mathworks page for [`dsp.MovingAverage`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.movingaverage-system-object.html):

"Exponential weighting — The block multiplies the samples by a set of weighting factors. The magnitude of the weighting factors decreases exponentially as the age of the data increases, but the magnitude never reaches zero. To compute the average, the algorithm sums the weighted data."

So there is no real averaging window as you use all your signal up to time t (exponentially weighted) for the mean value at that instant.
Of course older samples are weighted less than newer ones, and the parameter for that is that `ForgettingFactor`. I guess you could then define an "effective" averaging window as the number of samples whose weight is larger than a threshold.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like `dsp.MovingAverage` can return the weights itself, but you can calculate them yourself. From the Mathworks page,

[image: equation]

where [image: w] is the weight for the Nth sample and [image: lambda] is your forgetting factor. Remember to initialize the weight for the first sample to 1, so that you could have something like:

```
w = zeros(length(x),1); % where x is your signal
w(1) = 1; % initialize the weight for the first sample
for i = 2:length(x)
    w(i) = lambda*w(i-1) + 1; % calculate the successive weights
end
```

To have then the averaging window for the `N-th` sample I would probably then normalize the weights from 1 to `N` with respect to the their sum:

```
thr = 1.e-3; % your threshold, you'll probably have to play with this a bit
lengthAveragWdw = zeros(length(x),1);
for i = 1:length(x)
    wi = w(1:i); % weights used to calculate the moving average up to the i-th sample
    wi = wi./sum(wi); % normalize the weights
    lengthAveragWdw(i) = sum(wi >= thr); % count the number of samples whose weight is greater than the threshold
end
```

where `thr` is a threshold value that you have to decide beforehand.

Comment: Again, there is no real averaging window for the exponentially weighted moving average, so you can't "apply" it.